# WPF - InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage changing language for entire operating system

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF project in which I am trying to create a textbox which will be of a specific language input based on the culture that has been bound to it. Please refer the code below.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0"
              Width="220"
              Height="30"
              InputLanguageManager.InputLanguage="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=CurrentCulture}" />
```

The language input works fine for the textbox. But the problem is when I switch to any another application (Notepad, browser etc) the language is not reset back to the original system language. Instead I have to manually change the system language from the control panel.

How do I make the Language Input change only for that textbox.

Thanks in advance.